# Как обновить страницу в браузере используя node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Например, у меня есть ссылка. (допустим https://ru.stackoverflow.com ). Как мне используя node js обновить страницу, имея её ссылку?

Answer (score 0):

С помощью NodeJS никак, а javascript вот так:

```
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: а как в этом случае указать ссылку?

Comment: Этот код обновляет текущею страницу открытую в браузере, если вы хотите перенаправить пользователя на какую-то другую страницу то так `window.location.href = 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com ';